# WordPress: Redirecting from "day and month" to "post name" permalink format not working on Chrome for Android

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

We just migrated a wordpress.com blog to self hosted, paid for the redirect on wordpress.com and on our self hosted WordPress website we wanted to change the permalink format from "day and month" (/2017/12/31/postname) to "post name" (/postname) which would break the paid wordpress.com redirect, so we needed to create an internal redirect that redirects from day and name permalink format to post name permalink format.

I added the redirect rule to htacces that does exactly this, and noticed in Google Analytics that a bunch of people coming from Google Search are directed to 404 pages. Prior to finding this out, I tested the redirect on desktop by Googling one of our posts, and the redirect worked fine. However, when I tested it on android phone in chrome, it seems to add /amp behind the url (/postname/amp) for some reason which returns error 404.

The rewrite rule I added to htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am paying for the redirect on wordpress.com and the website has been officially launched and now a bunch of people googling for our posts are directed to 404 page.

Some of the posts are redirected fine on Android and most are directed to postname/amp, so I'm guessing the rewrite rule is not fully correct.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to htaccess and it sort of works now. It splashes the 404 page for a split second and then redirects to the right post.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/(.*)$ 
  RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```